# FreeSwitch Start Gives this Error: ==>freeswitch.service failed. See 'systemctl status freeswitch.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details

Tags: freeswitch

When I try to start Freeswitch using bellow command :

> /etc/init.d/freeswitch

It gives errors:-

> [....] Starting freeswitch (via systemctl): freeswitch.serviceJob for
>   freeswitch.service failed. See '**systemctl status
>   freeswitch.service**' and '**journalctl -xn**' for details.  failed!

Then I run this systemctl status freeswitch.service command that time it gives me this error:

> ● freeswitch.service - freeswitch    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/freeswitch.service; enabled)    Active: failed
>   (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2016-03-29 00:52:08 EDT; 8s ago
>   Process: 25997 ExecStart=/usr/bin/freeswitch -u freeswitch -g
>   freeswitch -ncwait $DAEMON_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Mar 29 00:52:07  systemd[1]: Failed to start freeswitch. Mar 29
>   00:52:07  systemd[1]: Unit freeswitch.service entered failed state.
>   Mar 29 00:52:08  systemd[1]: freeswitch.service start request repeated
>   too quickly, refusing to start. Mar 29 00:52:08  systemd[1]: Failed to
>   start freeswitch. Mar 29 00:52:08 media03 systemd[1]: Unit
>   freeswitch.service entered failed state.

Then I run journalctl -xn this command it gives me this error:

> > -- Logs begin at Tue 2016-03-22 15:12:38 EDT, end at Tue 2016-03-29 01:17:01 EDT. -- Mar 29 01:05:54  freeswitch[26066]: FreeSWITCH[26066]
> >     Error starting system! pid:26067 Mar 29 01:05:54  systemd[1]:
> >     freeswitch.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1 Mar
> >     29 01:05:54  systemd[1]: Failed to start freeswitch.
> >     -- Subject: Unit freeswitch.service has failed
>
> ### -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Unit freeswitch.service has failed.
>
> > -- The result is failed. Mar 29 01:05:54  systemd[1]: Unit freeswitch.service entered failed state. Mar 29 01:17:01  CRON[26073]:
> >     pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) Mar 29
> >     01:17:01  CRON[26074]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report
> >     /etc/cron.hourly) Mar 29 01:17:01  CRON[26073]:
> >     pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root

Freeswitch.log

```
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'ul'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'ulaw'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'al'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'alaw'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'adpcm'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1183 Deleting File Format 'vox'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:2008 Stopping: mod_sndfile
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [DEBUG] switch_loadable_module.c:1330 Write lock interface 'en' to wait for existing references.
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [NOTICE] switch_loadable_module.c:1338 Deleting Say interface 'en'
2016-03-18 13:13:16.027486 [CONSOLE] switch_loadable_module.c:2011 mod_say_en has no shutdown routine
```

Comment: You didn't provide any details, so what kind of an answer do you expect?

Comment: @deep-patel add the the last lines from the freeswitch.log file, normally in /var/log/freeswitch

Comment: @DeepPatel not enough info there. Need all lines of that log that relate to attempting to start FreeSWITCH. So, mark down the time you started FreeSWITCH, and copy paste all lines from that point.

Comment: @BIGMOOSE  Thanks ,There is no change in freeswitch log when i start freeswitch. This log was already there in file /var/log/freeswitch.

Comment: @DeepPatel when you start FreeSWITCH, if you see NOTHING in var/log/freeswitch to indicate something, then the FreeSWITCH application is literally not starting.

This suggests it's more related to your init script not working properly, as suren suggested in their answer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is related to your init script is not working properly. 
so try below

```
/usr/local/freeswitch/bin/freeswitch
```

If still problem exist just try to killall freeswitch processes. 
Then again start the freeswitch